# Знаки препинания при повторяющемся слове

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужно ли перед союзом "и" ставить какой-нибудь знак препинания в таком контексте:
"Сначала все было понятно. Дружба и дружба. Но теперь в их отношениях появилось что-то новое".

Answer (score 1):

> Сначала все было понятно. Дружба и дружба. Но теперь в их отношениях появилось что-то новое.

Похожие примеры с повтором глагола:

> Да оставь ты его, Мара, ну, сказал и сказал, и что?
>
> Однажды в компании, будучи навеселе, я представил ее: «Знакомьтесь, моя жена». Сказал и сказал. А она ждала.
>
> «В Западной Германии Солженицын мог бы беспрепятственно жить и работать». Сказал ― и сказал. Высылка ― могла быть, но она и прежде уже не раз быть могла, да никогда к ней не подкатывало.
>
> Можно сделать вывод, что союз "и" соединительный и нет знака или ставится тире, если подчеркивается пауза.

Answer (score 0):

"Дружба и дружба"-это выражение в корне не есть правильным,с точки зрения грамматики, более верная альтернатива-"дружба дружбой".

- Если же принять во внимание вышесказанное то становится понятно что запятую ставить не надо т.к. дружба-выступает в качестве подлежащего, а дружбой- сказуемое
- Если пойти по более простому пути-то между однородными членами речи с союзом не ставятся знаки препинания, какими и являются "Дружба и дружба"